# Array to string conversion with SQL 2008 and PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I have searched around here and other sources for a solution to this issue but so far no luck finding the answer that solves the issue.

When trying to query and fetch the result from a MS SQL 2008 database I get an Array to string conversion error in the sqlsrv_query line.

This is the php code for accessing and querying.

```
 <?php
/* Specify the server and connection string attributes. */
$serverName = "DATABASE";
$connInfo = array( "Database"=>"Suggestion");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Suggestions";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) OR die(sqlsrv_errors());

$val=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $val;

?>
```

**EDIT:**
As requested the actual error code below:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\DBTest\index.php on line 24

When taken into context of the entire file index.php line 24 is:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) OR die(sqlsrv_errors());
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Post the actual error.

Comment: Are you sure it's that line? `echo $val;` will cause a notice as `$val` is an array. Use `print_r($val);`

Comment: @JasonMcCreary The error is now posted as an edit to the original post. Thank you.

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: I am all for learning, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not print an array with 'echo' you have to use either 'print_r()' or var_dump()

Comment: Thank you, I realized that after posting the code and fixed that however the code wont execute to that point with the standing error. Thank you though.